# nvm: install fails on BSD while building from source

Tags: node.js, linker, freebsd, clang++, nvm

*System Info: FreeBSD 11.3-RELEASE-p3, amd64*

---

I have tried using nvm to install node `v12.16.2`, `v10.20.1`, and `v10.15.3`, however it fails building from source (no binary available for pull on BSD) with the same error on all three:

```
/usr/bin/ld:/usr/home/ifiht/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v12.16.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/tools/v8_gypfiles/libv8_libbase.a: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/bin/ld:/usr/home/ifiht/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v12.16.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/tools/v8_gypfiles/libv8_libbase.a:1: syntax error
```

Configure completes successfully:

```
$>./configure --prefix=/home/ifiht/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.2 <
INFO: configure completed successfully
gmake -C out BUILDTYPE=Release V=0
```

and the last command before failure is:

```
/usr/bin/clang++ -o /usr/home/ifiht/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v12.16.2/files/out/Release/bytecode_builtins_list_generator -pthread -rdynamic -m64 -Wl,--export-dynamic  -Wl,--start-group /usr/home/ifiht/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v12.16.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/bytecode_builtins_list_generator/deps/v8/src/builtins/generate-bytecodes-builtins-list.o /usr/home/ifiht/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v12.16.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/bytecode_builtins_list_generator/deps/v8/src/interpreter/bytecode-operands.o /usr/home/ifiht/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v12.16.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/bytecode_builtins_list_generator/deps/v8/src/interpreter/bytecodes.o /usr/home/ifiht/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v12.16.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/tools/v8_gypfiles/libv8_libbase.a -L/usr/local/lib -lexecinfo -Wl,--end-group
```

**I'm out of troubleshooting ideas, if anyone knows how to enable nvm install verbosity that would also help, not sure why the linker is trying to read random .a (assembly?) files??**

Comment: What's output of `file /usr/home/ifiht/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v12.16.2/files/out/Release/obj.target/tools/v8_gypfiles/libv8_libbase.a`? Also note that there are binary packages for node, run `pkg search node`.

Comment: @Rob, the question is definitely a nvm/node compilation question, which would make this the correct location?

Comment: @arrowd, yes there are workarounds but nvm being the primary version control manager for node I'd like to get this working.

Comment: @arrowd, the file command doesn't work as it looks like the cache is purged after the compilation fails..